# How do I call this method? (Objective C)

Tags: methods, call

I have this method which will report a score to game center:

```
   - (void)reportScore: (int64_t) forCategory: (NSString*) category
{
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = passedint;

    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            // handle the reporting error
        }
    }];
}
```

Now I have an ibaction to try to call that method but I am not able to figure it out..

```
- (IBAction)uploadscore {

passedint = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Scoreoneplayer"];
NSLog(@"%i", passedint);

[self reportScore:(passedint)forCategory :(NSString *) category];

}
```

passedint is the int I want to upload to Game Center. If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[self reportScore: passedint forCategory: @"Put your category here"];
```

You shouldn't need to provide types in the method call.

Comment: I did like you said but I get may not respond to reportScore:forCategory:
.h
- (void)reportScore:(int64_t)forCategory :(NSString *)category;

.m
- (IBAction)uploadscore {
 
 passedint = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"Scoreoneplayer"];
 NSLog(@"%i", passedint);
 
 NSString *string = @"Easy Category";
 [self reportScore: passedint forCategory:string];
 
}

Comment: Could have something to do with the fact that forCategory wants an int64_t and not an int?